# Custom control constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, custom-controls

ALL,

I am trying to understand how C# WinForms creates a custom control. I made a custom control based on the group box. Depending on some value I am creating a different set of controls inside.
I also successfully added this control to the Visual Studio toolbox and can drag-and-drop it on the form itself.
Since the creation of control will depend on some variable I made it a property in this class. It is visible in the properties list in the Visual Studio.

Here is the pseudo code of the control.

```
public partial class MyGroupBox : System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
{
    private int m_type;
    public RadioButton price;
    public RadioButton rb13;
    public int type
    {
        get { return m_type; }
        set { m_type = value; }
    }

    public MyGroupBox()
    {
        m_type = type;
        InitializeComponent();
        price = new RadioButton();
        if (type == 3)
        {
            rb13 = new RadioButton();
        }
    }
```

However after dragging the control to the form, I found that in the designer source code - `Form1.Designer.cs` - the control is created as:

```
this.entry = new MyGroupBox(this.components);
```

and therefore, when the program runs my empty constructor is not called.

My questions are:

1. What is this constructor with `this.components` parameter?
2. Since I can't manually edit `Form1.Designer.cs`, how to properly make this work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see this kind of behavior.

Comment: @AmiramKorach, you mean there is no such constructor?

Comment: Do you have a copy/paste error? Your current code won't compile because you have a "else if" without a previous "if" in your constructor.

Comment: Also, where are you getting "type"? It's not being passed into the constructor so it has to be set after the object is instantiated. Your logic for the radiobuttons should probably fall in your type property setter.

Comment: It is not an answer, just suggestion not to use designer. Use your control manually from code

Comment: My form doesn't use this constructor nor I see this constructor.

Comment: @itsme86, yes, that was copy/paste error, fixed. The type shuld be set thru the properties of the control in the Visual Studio. I will try to move this logic in the property setter. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @itsme86, moving the conditions to the property setter fixed the issue. Now I can even visually see everything in the designer. Thank you. Unfortunately I can't mark this as solved, but I just voted the comment up.